# How to detect of tap gesture is from uiwebview or self.view?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, onclick, uitapgesturerecognizer

Hello everyone I have a uitapgesture on my view using the following code :

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap= [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(TAPGestureRecognizer)];
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
    tap.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

And I have a uiwebview as a subview in my UIview. The problem is that on the uivewview HTML it had a onclick(); which in turn is calling the tapgesture. Any help?

Comment: i look your cod eit's not any mistake so where the exact problem you have..

Comment: the problem is that i have a tapgesture in the uiview which calls a method. And the uiview has a uiwebview . so i should differentiate if the user tapped on the uiwebview for example a link or on the self.view.

Comment: so you need to add [self.webview addGestureRecognizer:tap] adding new tap gesture recognizer to your webview beacuse only one gesture recognizer for single view

Comment: OK thanks :). I am facing another pb . Suppose i have a uibutton in the uiview. So how to diffenriate the touchupinside and the tap gesture. becaus enow when i am clicking on the uibutton its calling the action set in the uitouchupinside and also the tap gesture.

Comment: GestureRecognizer.enabled = NO; call these method on button... decleration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FirstView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"shape1.jpg"];
    FirstView.tag=1;
    FirstView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    [FirstView addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(firstimagetouch:)]];


    SecondWebView.tag=2;
    SecondWebView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    [SecondWebView addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(firstimagetouch:)]];


-(void)firstimagetouch:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    UIView * view=sender.view;

    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)view.tag);
}
```

try like this first add gesture recognizer to view and then your webview according to give him tag value and get tag value. and do what you want.