# iOS UITapGestureRecognizer and UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a viewcontroller, which contains a web view.

I'd like to add two gesturerocignizers to the viewController's view:
One UITapGestureRecognizer and one UILongPressureGestureRecognizer.

Here's the code:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(backToDashboards:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(backToDashboards:)];

doubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
doubleTapGesture.delegate = self;

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapGesture];
```

My view hierarchy:

```
-ViewController
 |
 |-View (added the gesture recognizers for this view)
   |-WebView
```

I've added the `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` method with `return YES`

But if I long press the screen nothing happens, only if the press' location is on a place where nothing can be scrolled in the webview.

The double tap recognizer doesn't work at all.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: i have no idea sorry.

Comment: I just looked at my gesture recognizers and none of the selectors  take an argument. Try taking out the colon on (backToDashboards:) and putting a log statement in the backToDashBoards method.

Comment: The argument is the sender

Comment: Thanks kennyevo, I didn’t think gesture recognizers had a sender. Now I know.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that because your webview is on top of your view, the app doesnt know if you are tapping the webview or self.view. Check out this reply [How to detect of tap gesture is from uiwebview or self.view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887757/how-to-detect-of-tap-gesture-is-from-uiwebview-or-self-view)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, but I don't think that this is the problem. I edited the original question. (added my view hierarchy)

Answer (score -1):

try with below code.Where u r adding gester in you code?
below code is working for me.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    { 
      [super viewDidLoad];
      UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
      longPress.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
      [self.view addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

      // if u want to add gesture for u webview,
      //[self.webview addGestureRecognizer:longPress]
    }

    -(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
    {
    }

    //You should enable simultaneous gesture recognition   

          - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
            {
                return YES;
            }
```